# Google Form - Updates made after release

Tags: google-forms

I created a quiz in Google Forms and released the scores to the students with my feedback. I am a big proponent of students revising their work, so I allow them to "edit after submit." However, while I can see that that students have edited their responses (see image), I am unable to find where the edited/updated responses are. It only shows me their original answer. The spreadsheet is the same way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Updates made after release]